# InvalidConfigurationException while creating a bundle in symfony by console

Tags: php, symfony

I want to generate a bundle in symfony2 with the following command:

```
php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=MyApp/SecurityBundle --format=yml
```

but when running this command I get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
The child node "providers" at path "security" must be configured.
```

I just started learning symfony. I can not figure out why I get this? is `SecurityBundle` is a reserved name? I read in symfony tutorial where there was a bundle named `AcmeSecurityBundle`, If it is a reserved name and I can not use it how the `AcmeSecurityBundle` is created? I don't have any problem in creating a bundle in other names.

Here's my `app/config/security.yml` content:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous:  ~
            form_login:
                login_path:     login
                check_path:     login_check
```

Comment: are you using the symfony standard edition?

Comment: Yes I downloaded Symfony_standard with vendors

Comment: can you post your `app/config/security.yml` content?

Comment: @JamesHalsall I just did it

Comment: configure provider in the security section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need provider in security.yml like:

```
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                user: { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
```

[Check out default security.yml.](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/config/security.yml)

Comment: I founded that I also have to define `ROLE_USER` and `ROLE_ADMIN` roles